# How to vertically stack navbar elements on collapse expansion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the `navbar-collapse` button, the elements from the `navbar` expand but they're not vertically aligned. How would you do this by keeping `Link5` and `Link6` right-aligned on the `navbar`?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sushiknives/yvgr92c3/1/

EDIT: `nav-pills` seems to be the issue. If I replace it with `navbar-nav` it automatically stacks vertically. In that case is there a way to recreate the `nav-pills` effect?

Comment: With UX design, typically you would make each link be it's own entity on a line and span the entire width. (some people have fat fingers, others don't know where they are clicking etc.) I would personally just make them do that.

Comment: What do you mean by making each line it's own entity? I tried to give each one a different class and then set each one to `width: 100%`, but then the elements on the navbar aren't listed horizontally.

Comment: If you drag the result section to the left in the JSFiddle, you'll see what the `navbar` should look like on a desktop screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use flexbox property `flex-direction : column` to stack it vertical hope this will help you

```css
body {
  width: 100% margin: auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.navbar {
  background: #FFFFFF
}
.nav {
  width: 100%
}
.nav a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<title>Navabar Test</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="texthover_test.css">

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li><a href="#">Link1</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link4</a>

          </li>
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link5</a>

          </li>
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Link6</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It stacks the elements vertically when you expand the `navbar-collapse` button. But on a large desktop screen size it doesn't list the links horizontally across the `navbar`. Is there any way to solve with just HTML and CSS? Or is there a jQuery or javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand your question. The li has to be full width of the parent element or you can shorten the width of the ul itself and make the li the same width as the ul. Adjust as needed.

```
 .nav li{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

[See it stacked as you want](http://jsfiddle.net/11j1Lnyx/1/)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the links listed horizontally on a large screen-size, but stacked vertically (not necessarily centered) on a smaller screen-size when the `navbar-collapse` button is used.

Comment: The links are stacked vertically on expansion of `navbar-collapse`, but they don't go back to being horizontally listed on a full size screen. If you drag the result section of the JSFiddle way to the left you'll see what I mean. The `collapse` button only shows up only when the screen is small enough.

Comment: Are you trying to make it responsive? if the answer is yes, I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what element of the page you you are asking about. The `collapse` button needs to be clickable and a dropdown will appear. I'm trying to have the links in the dropdown be vertically stacked and responsive in the sense that they still have to link to other pages. But when the dropdown is closed, and the page is dragged to be full-size the dropdown button dissapears and the links on the `navbar` should be horizontally listed as opposed to vertically stacked.